# Caliburn Micro Conductor.Collection.AllActive not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, caliburn.micro

I have tried to activate multiple windows in application using Caliburn Micro with Conductor.Collection.AllActive

Steps Followed:

Inhertited MainHomeViewodel from Conductor.Collection.AllActive

1)created property

```
public ExploreViewModel Explorer {
   get; private set;  
 }
```

2) Created ContentControl with name as property name

```
<ContentControl x:Name="Explorer" />
```

3)Activated viewmodel with property

```
Explorer = new ExplorerViewModel();
ActivateItem(Explorer );
```

After execution of above mentioned code its instantiating ExplorerViewModel but doesnt go to View's constructor or showing View .

Any problem with above implementation or do i need to do anything more to activate item.

Please Help!

Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
    public class MainHomeWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.AllActive
    {
      protected override void OnInitialize()
      {
       base.OnInitialize();
       ShowExplorer();
       }
        public void ShowExplorer()
        {

            Explorer = new ExplorerViewModel();
            ActivateItem(Explorer );

        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the whole class? Where are you calling `ActivateItem(Explorer)`?

Comment: @FCin  Edited question , please check .Its calling ExplorerViewModel but not showing view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Conductor.Collection.AllActive` uses `Items` property. If you want to display multiple Screens at once, you have to add them to `Items` property.

Then, because your views are stored in `Items` property, you want to bind your view to `Items`. This is an example:

Conductor:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.AllActive
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        Items.Add(new ChildViewModel());
        Items.Add(new ChildViewModel());
        Items.Add(new ChildViewModel());
    }
}
```

Conductor view (note, because we show collection of items we want to use `ItemsSource` not `ContentControl`):

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="Items"></ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Child screen:

```
public class ChildViewModel : Screen
{
}
```

Child view:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Width="50" Height="50" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5"></Border>
</Grid>
```

---

EDIT: Regarding discussion in comments, here is how you can use `IWindowManager` to show multiple windows:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Screen
{

    public ShellViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        var window1 = new ChildViewModel();
        var window2 = new ChildViewModel();

        windowManager.ShowWindow(window1);
        windowManager.ShowWindow(window2);

        window1.TryClose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try this way . One more doubt after adding the viewmodel into Items we don't need to call ActivateItem method ?

Comment: @VyasDev For `Conductor.Collection.AllActive`, `ActivateItem()` internally does the same thing as `Items.Add`. You can use whichever you want really.

Comment: Now ChildViewModel's view is User Control ,but my requirement is to add  Windows instead of UserControls .So can we use  ContentControl  instead of ItemsControl to hold multiple window Or how we can achieve it ?

Comment: @VyasDev So you don't want to use Conductors then. You want to use `IWindowManager` and use `ShowWindow()` method.

Comment: @VyasDev Updated my answer.

Comment: Hello @Fcin, When i am activating multiple viewmodel via first method, but when activating second viewmodel first viewmodel is getting blank or FIrst window is getting blank, why its happening ? Any Idea ?

Comment: @VyasDev Can you update your question with code that is causing problems?