# C# Caliburn Micro managing windows/views

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am currently developing a WPF App in C#. I am using Caliburn Micro as Framework. The MainWindow (ShellView) consists mainly of a left and a right part. Both parts are TabControls. On the left side I have 3 tabs and on the right side I have 6 tabs.

Currently I'm instantiating the 9 ViewModels of the 9 views with the constructor of the ShellViewModel, and then I bind the View with a ContentControl to the TabControl.

Normally with Caliburn Micro that could be handled better with the Conductor-class. I could create a list and bind that list to the TabControl and that's it.

But the problem is I have the Items-Collection only once, because it's inherited from the Conductor-class. So if I bind the left TabControl to the same Items as the right TabControl I will have the same tabs on both sides, which is not what I want to have.

Is there a way to have 2 independent Items-collections?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a separate view model for each side of your main screen. Each of these view models can then inherit from the `Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive` class. Your shell view model would then be composed of two sub-view models. Your shell view would also be composed of two content controls where each of the sub-view models and sub views are to be displayed.

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.AllActive {
   public LeftSideViewModel LeftSide { get; set; }
   public RightSideViewModel RightSide { get; set; }

   public ShellViewModel(LeftSideViewModel leftSide, RightSideViewModel rightSide) {
      LeftSide = leftSide;
      RightSide = rightSide;
      ActivateItem(leftSide);
      ActivateItem(rightSide);
   }
}

<UserControl x:Class="Workbench.Views.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ContentControl x:Name="LeftSide" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

        <ContentControl x:Name="RightSide"/>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>

public class LeftSideViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive {
   public LeftSideViewModel(...) {
       ActivateItem(yourTabViewModel);
       ActivateItem(anotherTabViewModel);
       ...
   }
}

public class RightSideViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive {
   public RightSideViewModel(...) {
       ActivateItem(yourTabViewModel);
       ActivateItem(anotherTabViewModel);
       ...
   }
}

<UserControl x:Class="Workbench.Views.LeftSideView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="Items" BorderThickness="0" TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabText}" />
                        <!-- The grid will not appear (collapsed) if the tab cannot be closed -->
                        <Grid Visibility="{Binding CloseTabIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <!-- The tab close button -->
                            <Button x:Name="CloseTab" Cursor="Hand" Focusable="False" Content="X" cal:Message.Attach="[Click] = [CloseTab($this)]" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you very much for your help. I think this answer was spot on. I implemented the 2 new view models and added the features like to described and it works like it should. There is only one little thing I had to change. I edited your post because Conductor needs to be Conductor<T>

Comment: There is no more a synchronous method  ActuvateItem that can be called in the ctor.
Use "Items.Add" - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51079965/1361096